# How to solve instant pc shutdown

Tags: hardware-failure, shutdown

My pc has an instant shutdown problem in different times. Sometimes when i am playing a game, sometimes i am develping web applications on Visual Studio, sometimes just browsing the web.

It hangs and becomes unresponsive. Sometimes it goes to hibernate like state (power signal on case bips) and never comes back. Sometimes just shutdowns instantly and power goes off.

I tracked temperatures with Speedfan, and didn't see any overheat hardware.
Usually temperatures are like that:
CPU: 41 C
GPU: 30 C 
HD1: 39 C (Western Digital 500 GB)
HD2: 33 C (Western Digital 1500 GB)

I couldn't detect which hardware or heat issue causes that.

How can i figure out the exact cause of problem? Any ideas?

Thanks
RAM: CORSAIR CMZ8GX3M2A1600C9 Vengeance 8GB (2x4GB) DDR3 1600Mhz CL9 XMP Dual Kit 
Power Supply: Thermaltake TR2 600 W
Graphics card: MSI N460GTX Nvidia Chipset

My configuration is as follows: 
CPU: AMD Phenom II X6 1055T 2.8GHz 9MB AM3 938p Cpu (Not overclocked ever, working on 2.8 ghz)
Mainboard: ASUS M5A88-V Evo Amd 880G DDR3 2000MHz Sata3 Usb3.0 16x AM3+ OS: Windows 7 Professional 64 bit

Comment: A failing power supply could cause your issue.  You could test it with a power supply tester, or if you are handy you could use a multi-meter, or you could simply swap it out with a known good power supply and see if the problem continues.

Comment: I've had similar issues with bad RAM as well.  While you're troubleshooting, you might try removing one stick of RAM and see if the problems disappear, and if not, try swapping sticks.

Comment: I've had similar issues with "green" power supplies in that they couldn't tolerate noise in the power line.  This happened with a home system (CPU would shut off whenever the fridge came on) and at work (two high end servers would shut down whenever the vacuum was run).  The work-around in both cases was to use a good UPS (the cheap ones don't produce a "true" sine wave).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I checked RAMs and PSU with using another working items, and problem still occurs. I have an idea about the motherboard, motherboard has an onboard ATI card (Integrated ATI/AMD Radeon™ HD 4250 GPU), and I have an Nvidia  graphics card. Motherboard has "Hybrid CrossFireX™" Support, but AFAIK it is an ATI/AMD  feature. Could it be the cause of the problem, but I have no proof of course. Only an idea. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally my problem is solved when I changed my mainboard. It seems to be a problem with mainboard, but I couldn't exactly figure the details out.